# What is the proper way to update a state inside of useEffect hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mouseevent

I need to update viewBox values of SVG when the user triggers a mouse wheel event.

```
  type viewBox = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    w: number;
    h: number;
  };

  const [viewBox, setViewBox] = useState<viewBox>({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: canvasArea.clientWidth,
    h: canvasArea.clientHeight,
  });


  useEffect(() => {
      svgContainer.onwheel = function (e: any) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var w = viewBox.w;
        var h = viewBox.h;
        var mx = e.offsetX; 
        var my = e.offsetY;
        var dw = w * Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 0.05;
        var dh = h * Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 0.05;
        var dx = (dw * mx) / svgSize.w;
        var dy = (dh * my) / svgSize.h;
        setViewBox(
          {
            x: viewBox.x + dx,
            y: viewBox.y + dy,
            w: viewBox.w - dw,
            h: viewBox.h - dh,
          }
        )
        scale = svgSize.w / viewBox.w;
        svg?.setAttribute(
          "viewBox",
          `${viewBox.x} ${viewBox.y} ${viewBox.w} ${viewBox.h}`
        );
      };
    ),[viewBox]}
```

When I update my viewBox state like this, it makes slowing down my page on every mouse wheel event. Why is this happening? Should I use a different method for watching viewBox state?

Comment: where are you using `viewBox` state ? only in useEffect?

Comment: Not only in useEffect. I am using useState hook because I need to get updated viewBox values in a different function. When I define a variable for viewbox values, I cannot get updated values outside of useEffect. Am I missing something?

Comment: delete viewBox from dependency array

Comment: Probably the issue is, that you aren't unmounting the `onwheel` eventlistener in your useEffect. Adding that might help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But unmounting the listener doesn't change this slowing issue. Therefore I decided to use variable declarations instead of useState, now it works as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing same state in useEffect which is in the dependency of useEffect will cause the rendering loop  thats why it make your page slow. when state change which is use in useEfect dependency the useEffect run again and state change again beacuse of this useEffect run again and again...

just do this in onClick event to avoid re rendering

```
const onClickUpdateSvg = () => {
    svgContainer.onwheel = function (e: any) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var w = viewBox.w;
      var h = viewBox.h;
      var mx = e.offsetX; // mouse x
      var my = e.offsetY;
      var dw = w * Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 0.05;
      var dh = h * Math.sign(e.deltaY) * 0.05;
      var dx = (dw * mx) / svgSize.w;
      var dy = (dh * my) / svgSize.h;
      setViewBox({
        x: viewBox.x + dx,
        y: viewBox.y + dy,
        w: viewBox.w - dw,
        h: viewBox.h - dh,
      });
      scale = svgSize.w / viewBox.w;
      svg?.setAttribute(
        "viewBox",
        `${viewBox.x} ${viewBox.y} ${viewBox.w} ${viewBox.h}`
      );
    };
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it still does not prevent re-rendering. The problem was solved by using variable declaration instead of useState.